# How to post site contents into a facebook wall?

Tags: php, facebook

**Possibility one:**

On this website each user as an account. 
I wish to allow, each registered user to publish something into their own facebook page.

Is this possible ?

If not,

**Possibility two:**

On this website, each user as an account.
I wish to allow each registered user to publish something into one specific facebook page (created by us);

**Additional notes regarding possibility two: **
We have a web application. http://www.mysite.com 
We have that web application connected with our facebook account.

Now, should we create a facebook application ? Or can we "simple" use the API to publish something on our facebook wall ?

**Can someone that already did this, please provide me, the general steps for accomplish such a task ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibility one is possible. It's called using the Facebook Graph API. You register for an API key through Facebook Developers, and then you use their example code to put a button on your page that takes care of the users current login session with Facebook.

After that, you can send requests through the Facebook Graph API that allow you to post to the users wall, and access really any information you want about them.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/